# How to save a sample response for every different response code in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to sample response data for every single different response code.

For Example, if there are 4 different kinds of response codes received in a test, namely 200, 403, 400, 500, then I want to save one response for each code and there should be 4 different files generated after this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File(prev.getResponseCode() + '.txt') << prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   ```
3. That's it, once you run your test the script will generate files like `200.txt`, `403.txt`, etc. in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

In the above code snippet `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the linked JavaDoc for the list of available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn more about other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JMeter's [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want exactly one sample for each response code, I propose to use a [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor).
Just some **pseudo code**:

```
case response code:
   200: 
       if !(200.log exists): write previous response to file
   400: 
       if !(400.log exists): write previous response to file
   403: 
       if !(403.log exists): write previous response to file
   500: 
       if !(400.log exists): write previous response to file
```